# Arrows/HXT and Type Signatures

Tags: haskell, types, monads, arrows, hxt

I am trying to learn Arrows in Haskell, so I am writing a simple application with the arrow based HXT library for XML. The examples in the HXT wikis and tutorials forgo function type signatures. However, I am quite fond of types and am trying to work out how to use them. This is where I have met a stumbling block. Given these functions:

```
readXml str = runX (readString [withValidate no] str)

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)
```

I figure they should be assigned the following signatures:

```
readXml ∷ String → IO [XmlTree]

atTag ∷ ArrowXml a ⇒ String → a XmlTree XmlTree
```

I am trying to hook these together using arrow syntax as such:

```
parseItem = proc str -> do
    desc <- text <<< atTag "description" <<< arr readXml -< str
    ...
```

However, if my my type-signatures are correct (GHC hasn't complained), I would need a way in which to combine monad syntax and arrow syntax to get the `XmlTree` out of and returned to `IO`.

I am unsure how to proceed. Anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `runX` in the definition of `readXml` "converts" an arrow into a function, and using `arr` in the definition of parseItem converts that function back into an arrow again. Now, doing it like this would be fine, except that `readString` returns an `IOStateArrow` (a special type alias for the `IOSLA` - IO State List Arrow), which should be treated not only as an `Arrow`, but more specifically as an `IOArrow`; meanwhile, you are treating it as a pure `Arrow` by rewrapping it using `arr`.

You have two options here:

1. Make `readXml = readString [withValidate no]`, so that `readXml :: String -> IOStateArrow s b XmlTree`. Then you can just do `... <<< readXml str` in `parseItem`.
2. Use `arrIO` to lift readXml into an IO arrow, which lets you use it the way you intended.

I would use option 1 in this case, since it seems superfluous to do this arrow-wrapping-unwrapping if there's no special reason for it.

Comment: I am confused. In scenario 1, readXml is not actually an arrow, rather a function that returns an arrow. How can this be used with arrow syntax as if it were one?

Comment: I forgot to remove the `-<` when I copied the code; it should be clearer now.